# How can I create a ClassLoader which will use a particular classpath?

Tags: java

In Java, how can I create a ClassLoader which will use a particular classpath (probably just a single jar file)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a `URLClassLoader` object.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, create a `URLClassLoader` as pointed out by @bmargulies. It's pretty easy to use, just pass an array of URLs into the constructor.

Maybe also check [this thread](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t148021-dynamically-change-the-classpath.html) and, in particular, [this post](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/showpost.php?p=638140&postcount=3) for some tips on how to use Java (hierarchical) ClassLoaders. I don't know what you want to do exactly but you may find it useful.